# When are environment variables available in flutter app?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, environment-variables

I'm using Flutter 3.3.10, on macOS 11.6, and I am trying to use env vars at runtime. For the sake of the test I have 2 prints, one in main() and 1 in the build() function, like so:
`print(const String.fromEnvironment('APPNAME'));`

When I run the app from terminal on an iOS simulator like so: `flutter run --dart-define=APPNAME=TEST_APP` I get 2 blank prints:

```
Xcode build done.                                           10.8s
flutter:
flutter:
```

It is only after I do a hot restart ('R') that it prints:

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 378ms.
flutter: TEST_APP
flutter: TEST_APP
```

Why are the env vars not available on the first run?

EDIT: Interestingly, I don't get that problem when I run the exact same app on an Android emulator.

Comment: I don't even get as far as you do on the iOS sim ... I never get a value :(

Comment: So this is just an issue with the iOS sim using env vars, and not a problem with the implementation?